# Get a string resource from "values" folder in Android

Tags: java, android, resources, string.xml

I have a default string that needs to be used on the app, no matter the language.

Thinking that it should be independent from the app language I did not put the string inside any of the `string.xml` files for the different languages. Instead I created another `myString.xml` file inside `values` folder, looking like that:

**myString.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="myStringResource">This text shall be available
for the entire app no matter the language
</string>
</resources>
```

But now I am not able to access this string.

Is it the wrong way to do that? And if yes, then how can I achieve the above explained scenario?

Comment: As far as I know this should work. Did you try it?

Comment: If it's just one string, you can store it in your preferences and then retrieve it wherever you want.

Comment: I tried different things like writing for example `String test = getString...`but Android Studio marks getString in red. How Should I call it?

Comment: Can you please post code where you try to get it ?

Comment: yep, if it's just one string why bother creating an xml file. regardless, how are you accessing the string?

Comment: If `getString` is marked red, then you are working in a class that does not extend from context. In what kind of class are you trying to do this? Is it an `Activity`, `Fragment` or something else?

Comment: I just tested it, created new file inside values named it mystrings.xml, and then added new string inside it callled it <string name="mystring">hi</string> and then called it using @string/mystring and it worked

Comment: As @0xDEADC0DE explain i think you trying to get that string with out side context reference class.

Comment: @Yamen, ok I might be doing something wrong then, thanks!

Comment: @Haresh, yes context might be the problem, the class is just `public class testString` nothing else

Comment: If you are trying to get inside a Class make sure you are inside Activity class or then pass your Context to another class and call it using that context. Something like context.getString(R.string.myString);

Comment: @eddie its the same thing with Toast to do Toasts in another classes you need to pass the context

Comment: thanks guys, I will fix it, im almost sure it is a context problem

Comment: @eddie alternative way is define such constant string on some app constant class with public static final declaration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To access Strings, you do as Berat said in his answer. From code using ID's (`R.string.resName`) and XML using the @string annotation: `@string/resName` to get the String.

However, when you use code (e.g. Java), you can't just use the ID. You also have to use `Context.getString(R.string.resName);` to get the actual String. So if you want to access the String from code and get it as a variable, you do this:

```
String res = context.getString(R.string.myStringResource);
```

I write `context` because it is a class in Context. You can, however, use Activity instances to get the String as well. If you are writing the code inside an activity, you can just write `String res = getString(R.string.myStringResource);`.

Activity means either extending Activity or AppCompatActivity (or a class that extends either on some level)

Comment: thanks, I will try that, I am almost sure that `Context` is the problem here